# Disable a SCO SCORM 2004

Tags: javascript, scorm2004

How would I disable a SCO with JavaScript?  SCORM 2004 4th edi.  I can't seem to hit the SCO with JS.  I can disable it using SCORM.  I ultimately want to disable the SCO after 3 attempts on a quiz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't disable the sco with javascript, but you can use navigation in JS to navigate to or away from the sco, if you've configured the sequencing and navigation correctly in the imsmanifest.xml --> [example gist shows how to use SCORM 2004 attemptLimit](https://gist.github.com/DB8-8BD/1a7e4e1c5d955ab6034ec6585a575bdd)

navigating SCO's with JS means you are setting the adl.nav.request to previous (in your test results page) if the user failed, or continue if they passed.